# How to autoplay one audio tag when the page has more than 20 audio tags loaded dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html5-audio

I have been trying to make a system in which there is a playlist loaded from MySQL database has to be played on different timings

For Eg : if it is 8 AM in the morning there is a song which needs to be played and it should change automatically when clock strucks 9 AM

```
<tr class="hidden" >
                <td start="'.strtotime($time_prev).'" finish="'.strtotime($time_next).'" style="padding:20px;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                Date: <strong>'.date("d M Y l",$current_date).'</strong> 
                                <p>Running from : '.$time_prev.' - '.$time_next.'</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                <p>
                                    <audio class="play_audio" controls loop>
                                       <source src="'.$result3["planet_mantra"].'" type="audio/mpeg">
                                       Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                                    </audio>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div
                    </td>
            </tr>
```

This is the PHP code , I remove the class hidden when the time stamp is between the start and finish time . But how should i play audio when the current div is visible.

Answer (score 0):

So in the same step, when you remove the class `hidden` you can add the `autoplay` property to your audio tag like this `<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>`
Hope that helps.

Comment: But since the autoplay feature will trigger all the audio tags which are not visible , this will not work ... I need only the current <tr> which doesn't has the class="hidden" to get autoplayed

Comment: But then you should be able to simply select the tr which has not the class hidden and from there you can select the audio tag, which is in that table-row and add the autoplay property only for that audio tag.

Comment: I have already done that , once the page loads it shows that the audio tag has this autoplay property but still the music is not playing